# Interpreting the math in this Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, indexing

This is definitely a newbie question, but it's bothered me for a long time.

I've yet to find a readable explanation for the -1 and +1 in iterations of lists like this one:

```
   # check for adjacent elements that are equal
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
        return True
return False
```

For context, the code is from here:

http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/code/birthday.py

I don't fully understand the purpose of -1 in the for loop. I think the +1 is saying "if any element in this ordered list is identical to the next element in the list, return True".

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: The `-1` is there because otherwise it would yield an `IndexError` when you got to the last loop and tried to access`i+1`. The `+1` means exactly what you think

Comment: Trace the execution, either by hand or with a `print` statement.  Once you've done that, let us know where you are not understanding how the loop handles limits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260003/how-does-list-indexing-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the entire answer, I am sorry if this answer is a bit confusing because of the order of how I typed it (i.e.  You should probably read List Indexes before reading the following paragraph).

For the code that you have, it will go through every element from the 0th index of the list all the way up to the 2nd last. It has a "-1" because the last element has no adjacent index. So if it went up to the index of the last element in the list, when it tries to find s[i+1] it will error, because there is no element after s[i].

You are correct in saying that s[i+1] will access the element after s[i].

**List Indexes**

List indexes start at 0. So:

```
[1,2,3] # Will have indexes:
#0 1 2 (They line up)
```

my_list[0] will access the first element, my_list[1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) will access the second element and so on.

However, len(my_list) will still return 3, even though my_list[3] will cause an error because it only goes up to my_list[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260003/how-does-list-indexing-work).

**Resources**

You may find that this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) will help you with list indexes, although it also covers splicing which is slightly more complex.

There is also a similar question which addresses your question slightly better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260003/how-does-list-indexing-work).